# Calculating the bounce solution numerically

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I would like to obtain a numerical solution to the following example bounce equations,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 a}{\partial t^2} &= \frac{1}{t^2} a(1-a)(1-3a)-\frac{b^2}{2}(1-a)\\
\frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial t^2} &= \frac{1}{t^2}b(1-a)^2-\frac{1}{t}\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}+b(b^2-1)
\end{align*}$$

with formal boundary conditions

$$ a(0)=b(0)=0, \; a(\infty)=b(\infty)=1,$$

although $a(x)=b(x)=1$ for any large value of $x$ should be fine as well.
If possible, I would like to do so by largely using built-in Mathematica functions. I have changed some of the numerical prefactors, but the essentials of the system are the same. Whenever I carry out this calculation with `NDSolve`, Mathematica complains about the system being stiff - I suspect this is due to the $\frac{1}{t^{(2)}}$ factors evaluated close to the origin. As a beginner to Mathematica and numerical methods, I really have no further tricks up my sleeve at the moment, so I would appreciate any good hint. I should mention that I have been able to find a solution by implementing a particular numerical method (an elaborate version of the Newton algorithm), but it would be much easier, arguably less error-prone and hopefully better scalable to more equations if I found a way of having Mathematica take care of it largely by itself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that $t = 0$ is a *singular point* of the system.  This is (as you suspect) due to the factors of $1/t$ and $1/t^2$ in the equations.  A straightforward implementation of an ODE solver will not be able to solve all the way to $t = 0$ in general, since the highest-order derivatives will diverge at that point for a general solution.

One way to get around this for a singular system is to use Mathematica to find an approximate solution near the singular point.  This allows us to "move the boundary" away from the singular point and solve over a domain $[\epsilon, T]$ (for some large $T$) that doesn't contain any points where Mathematica will obviously have trouble.   By finding an approximate solution near $t = 0$, we can find the approximate value of the solution at $t = \epsilon > 0$, perhaps in terms of some arbitrary parameters.  If $\epsilon$ is sufficiently close to zero, then $a(\epsilon)$ & $b(\epsilon)$ will be "close" to their "true" values in a solution with $a(0) = b(0) = 0$, and solving the equations over the domain $t \in [\epsilon, T]$ (for some large $T$) will give you a solution that should be "close" to the true solution.

In practical terms:  The solution should (hopefully) be expressible as a power series in terms of $t$;  and so we try an ansatz of a series solution that goes to zero at there.

```
eqns = {a''[t] - (1/t^2 a[t] (1 - a[t]) (1 - 3 a[t]) - b[t]^2/2 (1 - a[t])), 
        b''[t] - (1/t^2 b[t] (1 - a[t])^2 - 1/t b'[t] + b[t] (b[t]^2 - 1))}
seriesrules = {a -> Function[t, SeriesData[t, 0, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}, 1, 6, 1]],
               b -> Function[t, SeriesData[t, 0, {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5}, 1, 6, 1]]}
coeffrules = SolveAlways[Normal[eqns /. seriesrules] == 0, t]

(* {{a5 -> 0, b5 -> (b1 (11 + 96 b1^2))/2112, b4 -> 0, a4 -> -(b1^2/22), 
     b3 -> -(b1/8), a3 -> 0, b2 -> 0, a2 -> 0, a1 -> 0}} *)
```

This implies that near $r = 0$, the solution will have the form

```
approxsoln = Normal[({a[eps], b[eps]} /. seriesrules) /. coeffrules]

(* {-(1/22) b1^2 eps^4, b1 eps - (b1 eps^3)/8 + (b1 (11 + 96 b1^2) eps^5)/2112} *)
```

One can in principle then put the boundary at `eps` and integrate out to some large `T`.  By tweaking the value of `b1`, one can quickly narrow down the value of `b1` that leads to boundary condition one wants.  (This may be equivalent to the "elaborate Newton algorithm" method you describe in your question.)

Alternately, one could use `b1` and `eps` as parameters in a `ParametricNDSolve` call, and then use the root-finding methods of `FindRoot` to find the value for which `{a[inf], b[inf]}` takes on a particular value.

This said, I suspect that for the particular equations you've provided, there is no solution that is analytic at $t = 0$, for the simple solution that there is only one free parameter in the series expansion.  This means you effectively have to "hit a target" in 2-D ($a(\infty) = b(\infty) = 1$) with only one degree of freedom; it is likely that there is no value of $b_1$ that leads to such a solution.  Perhaps, though, the techniques I've described here will be useful for your actual problem.

Comment: A couple of things. First of all, thank you for your answer. Secondly, I do have a couple of questions on what you suggested. What exactly do you mean by ''putting the boundary at eps''? I understand that if I set eps=0, that series expansion of the functions will fulfill the BC at the origin, if that is what you mean; then I'd be left with setting a[x]=b[x]=1 for some arbitrarily large x in order to obtain b1. Or do you rather mean I set the left boundary at a symbolic eps and integrate the original equations up to some large t? I appreciate your effort, I'm afraid I'm just a bit lost.

Comment: Also, to get it out of the way - my original solution involves a variant of the finite difference method, which in the end leaves me with a discretized system of algebraic equations of which the Newton algorithm takes care. My algorithm works fine for this system of equations, but it does not yield the results I expect after adding another function. Today I've discovered that v12 of Mathematica has implemented in NDSolve the Method->FiniteElement (which I understand is their implementation of the Finite Difference method), and I was hoping someone could perhaps shed some light onto it.

Comment: @AlWaurora:  I've edited the first couple of paragraphs to better explain the technique.

Comment: Again, thank you very much.